# For a Quartus project what files must be added to a git repository?

Tags: quartus

A Quartus project generates huge number of files as we proceed with design compilation and debug automatically.

Provided that I wish to add my Quartus project to a Git repository and not just the hdl files, what are the files that I must add? The objective is that when we clone the repository, we can just open the project and click compile to compile the design. Nothing else needs to be "fixed" in this time.

Git is used for version control by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Quartus to generate a TCL file (click "Project → Generate TCL file for Project...") that will set up your project from scratch, including any generated IP you're using. So ultimately, all you need to save is that script, the Quartus Project File (.qpf) and all of your HDL source files. Building from a fresh clone is more than a single step, however:

- Open the project (the .qpf file)
- execute the setup script ("source" the .tcl file)
- click "Compile"

Comment: I shall have a look once I go back home in a few days. There is also the question on how the qsys design shall be version controlled via this tcl script. Qsys is for all intents and purposes an addon which generates its own files.

Comment: Yes, Qsys is its own can of worms, but there's a limited set of files (one per generated IP, IIRC) that you need to save, and there's a Qsys command to regenerate all of them -- and it works *most* of the time.